# Why does VS2013 have Typescript type information but no Intellisense?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

I just updated Visual Studio 2013 Update 3, which includes the typescript plugin, but I'm not getting member lists or code completion at all.

If I have a simple script like this:

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts"/>
window.onload = () => {
    var area = $("#game_area");
}
```

I still get the right type info - the variable area is of type "JQuery"

[image]

However when I try to get a variable's members I don't get any suggestions:

[image]

Is there any way to get typescript working?

Comment: Do you use ReSharper or any such plugins?

Comment: I use Update 2, but there it is an option in Tools -> Text Editor -> Typescript -> General called "Auto list members". Could it be that you need to check this?

Comment: @Mrchief Nope. My only extensions are PythonTools and NodeTools but I don't get Intellisense even in pure TS projects.

Comment: @Gustav I've had a look there and the box is already checked so it can't be that

Answer (score -2):

Just try hitting CTRL-Space to force intellisense.

If that doesn't work, then I would suggest doing a "repair" via the installation.  We have had devs that had problems with TypeScript ( VS update 3 ) - who had installed VS 2012 AFTER installing VS 2013.  A repair seemed to have worked.